# Move multiple graphics from one HTML page to another (shopping cart)

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

My website is a custom pen-making site where the customer must make three choices before finalizing their pen. They must choose a STYLE of pen, METAL type for components (band, tip) and COLOR of barrel (Wood or Acrylic). Those three choices are then shown in a preview graphic. How do I send that same graphic (all three choices) to a shopping cart or orders page? The  that contains these selections is "testParent". (It was programmed by someone I can no longer contact.)

How do I change the "onclick" to move the 3 graphics to another order/shopping cart page?
Thanks.

This is what I currently have and it works until I click the "send to cart" button. How do I use onclick? (all src's and variables are previously defined.) Can onlick send the 3 graphics to another page, or should I use some other code?

```
<div class="testParent">
    <img alt="" class="testBottom" id="picMaterial" src="" style="width: 600px;" />
    <img alt="" class="testTop" id="picStyle" src="" style="width: 600px" />
    <span class="testTitle" id="picTitle" ><span>
</div>
```

```
<tr style="height: 20px"><td style="font-size:22px; font-family: arial" colspan="3" align="center">
 This is the pen I want. Click to Send to Cart...<input type="button" value="Send To Cart"        class="button-29-Green" onclick="sendIt()"></td></tr>
<tr style="height: 20px"><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: You are talking about three images, but i can only see two `<img>` tags inside `testParent`. Either way, you could get the src from the `<img>` and send that information to the other site. To be able to tell you how best to send it, would require to know what the destination page looks like or how it would receive the data.

Comment: You are correct. There are three choices but only two images, plus the title of the chosen acrylic/wood. For the destination page I'm just creating an HTML page. I've read I shouldn't use localstorage as it is limited, What other way can I store/pass along these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to pass parameters in the query string when you load the shopping cart page.

- style = fountain/ballpoint/quill/whatever
- band = gold/silver/titanium/whatever
- tip = gold/silver/titanium/whatever
- barrel = wood/acrylic

Your code might look like this:

```
document.querySelector('input[type=button]').addEventListener('click', evt => {
   window.location.href = "/cart.html?style=fountain&band=gold&tip=titanium&barrel=wood"
})
```

The shopping cart page then references these parameters to display the correct image.

Comment: That would work but I don't know what the customer's choices are until it appears in the preview, so I can't pass unknown parameters to the shopping cart. If I copied the "testParent Div" into the shopping cart would it retain the correct values or would it look for new values?

Comment: (correct values=same values as the preview...)